# C++ cURL JSON error 3221226356 more then one time

Tags: c++, api, curl, nlohmann-json

Hi i got problem with API call when i try to send request secount time (while loop in main.cpp from sqlDB), for the first time everything is ok, but secount request get good JSON response but after that my problem close with

```
Process exited after 80.64 seconds with return value 3221226356
```

[full console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnD7B.png)
Api call script:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"
#include <sstream>
#include <windows.h>

//
using namespace std;

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};

static size_t
WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if (mem->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;
    return realsize;
}
    
double api_call(string asin){
    

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    

    string link = "https://api.rainforestapi.com/request?api_key=xxx";
    link += asin; 
    link += "&type=offers";
    int n = link.length();
    char link_char[n + 1];  
    strcpy(link_char, link.c_str());
    
    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
    chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    char* curlErrStr = (char*)malloc(CURL_ERROR_SIZE);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_slist* httpHeaders = NULL;
    if(curl) 
    {
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, link_char);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    /* get it! */
    
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    }
    
    ofstream oplik;
    oplik.open("test.json");
    oplik << chunk.memory;
    oplik.close();
    if (chunk.memory){
        free(chunk.memory);
    }
    
    

    ifstream fJson("test.json");
    stringstream buffer;
    buffer << fJson.rdbuf();
    auto json = nlohmann::json::parse(buffer.str());
    double price = json["offers"][0]["price"]["value"];
    fJson.close();
    return(price);
    
    
}
```

I add printf to see where it crash

```
printf("4");
curl_global_cleanup();
printf("5");
```

and i can see 4 but not 5, so i think cleanup() crush console, any idea ?

It is test so code is not good but works :)

Maybe someone can find whats wrong cuz i cant ;/

Comment: Not sure why you're using `link_char` (which isn't valid c++ due to the non-constant array size) rather than just passing `link.c_str()` directly to `CURLOPT_URL`

Comment: My guess would be `chunk.memory` isn't null terminated when you first allocate it, if `WriteMemoryCallback` doesn't get called (e.g if the request fails) then `oplik << chunk.memory` will have undefined behaviour

Comment: @AlanBirtles you're right, but it's not problem here i think.(about link_c_str())

Comment: @AlanBirtles so what should i do with that WriteMemoryCallback ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles i try with commented line with write to file and read from file and still same result.

Comment: @AlanBirtles i add to code:  
printf("4");
    curl_global_cleanup();
    printf("5");
to see in what step it crash and i can see 4 but not 5, so i think curl_global_cleanup(); crash console

Comment: Why are you calling `curl_global_cleanup` as part of `api_call`? Wouldn't it make more sense to call this at the end of `main` (or not at all)

Comment: do you call `curl_global_init` again at some point? If you've done `curl_global_cleanup` you can't use curl again until its been reinitialised